# Cannot iterate through Map in Angular 4

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am creating a frontend using Angular 4 and I came across a strange error. Whenever I execute the code below:

```
  private createProductTree(productData: Map<number, any>): Map<number, Node> {

    const productTree = new Map<number, Node>();

    // Iterate over menu-item objects.
    for (let key of productData.keys()) {

      const product = productData.get(key);
      if (product.type === 'menu-item') {
        const node = new Node(product);
        productTree.set(key, node);
      }

    }

    return productTree;
  }
```

I get the following error: `Type 'IterableIterator<number>' is not an array type or a string type.` in the `for (... of ...)` line.

I am not sure what I am doing wrong. The `for` code is the same as the one I saw [here](https://codecraft.tv/courses/angular/es6-typescript/mapset/).

Comment: According to [this discussion](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/6842), it could be related to the Javascript version that you are targeting. It should work for ES6.

Comment: @ConnorsFan, even in es6 this is not the correct way to iterate the Map as I mention in my answer. If one uses `keys()` there's no need to use `for..of`. `forEach` would be a better option

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are not iterating `Map` correctly. `Map` implements `iterable` interface and returns an array where first element is the key and the second element is the value. Here is an example [from the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/@@iterator):

```
var myMap = new Map();
myMap.set('0', 'foo');
myMap.set(1, 'bar');
myMap.set({}, 'baz');

for (var v of myMap) {
  console.log(v);
}
```

Logs:

```
["0", "foo"]
[1, "bar"]
[Object, "baz"]
```

So for your example it would be:

```
for (let entry of productData) {
  const product = entry[1];
  if (product.type === 'menu-item') {
    const node = new Node(product);
    productTree.set(entry[0], entry[1]);
  }
}
```

However, this requires `target=es6` in `tsconfig`.

If your target is `es5`, you can use it like this:

```
for (let entry of Array.from(productData.entries())) {
       ...
}
```

Or use  `forEach` instead:

```
Array.from(productData.entries()).forEach((entry)=> {
  const product = entry[1];
  if (product.type === 'menu-item') {
    const node = new Node(product);
    productTree.set(entry[0], entry[1]);
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi, I edited the code as you suggested, but I still have the same error: `Type 'Map<number, any>' is not an array type or a string type.` when I try to use the `for(... of ...)` loop. I also copied and pasted your example into my code and I got this error: `Type 'Map<any, any>' is not an array type or a string type.` Maybe it is something with Typescript.

Comment: what is your `target` in `tsconfig`? it should be `es6` to support `for..of` syntax correctly

Comment: I checked and my setting was `es5`. The loop worked when I changed it to `es6`, however I don't think that I should do this, because of compatibility issues. Is there another way to loop through this map without the `for(... of ...)`?

Comment: _Type 'Map<number, any>' is not an array type or a string type_ - yes, this is a problem with typescript. It thinks that only `array` and `string` is iterable

Comment: I am almost there... I changed the code to what you suggested, but I am still getting and error saying that `entries` is not a function: `Failed: productData.entries is not a function`. Maybe I have to import the `Map` class into my file, but I am not finding the right import.

Comment: @Felipe, try adding `es6` to the `lib` option as described [here](https://hackernoon.com/configuring-typescript-compiler-a84ed8f87e3#e6bd)

Comment: My `tsconfig.json` file already has an `"es2016"` option. I also added `"es6"` option as stated on that guide, but the result is the same.

Comment: Actually, I found out that the problem is not related to the `es6` setting, but rather how I am getting the `productData` map, which comes from an Observable. But the `for(... of ...)` problem was solved! Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (const key in productData) {  }
```

of is basically forEach and iterates over values, in accesses the keys of an object.